# How to produce a Subquery using non-generic Lambda2

Tags: linq

i'm very new to LINQ? please help me
How would you translate the following generic Lambda function into a lambda expression :

```
objects.Where(objects=>values.Contains(objects.DistrictId) );
```

I'm trying to create a full lambda expression without any  or direct call. Something like :

```
var innerItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Objects), "objects");
var innerProperty = Expression.Property(innerItem, "ID");
var innerMethodExpression = Expression.Call(innerProperty,null);
var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Objects, bool>>(innerMethodExpression, innerItem);

var outerItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int[]), "item");
var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(int) });

var containsMethodExpression = Expression.Call(innerMethodExpression, containsMethod, innerLambda);
var outerLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Objects, bool>>(containsMethodExpression, outerItem);

collection = collection.AsQueryable<Objects>().Where(outerLambda);
```

But i can't understand what is wrong

Comment: In your mind, how do you differentiate between a lamda function and a lambda expression?

Comment: @Mithrandir I guess he meant `Expression<Func<...>>`. But @OP: doesn't just passing a normal lambda work here? Usually the lambda gets passed in as `Expression`s automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,

The Lambda function is

```
objects.Where(objects=>values.Contains(objects.DistrictId) );
```

so your lambda expression should be

```
Expression<Func<Objects, int>> ObjectsExp = objects=>values.Contains(objects.DistrictId);
```

Assume DistrictId is integer type for your out Result.